# Load javascript via Firebug console

Tags: javascript, firebug

How can I load a javascript file via Firebug console ?

This would be useful in development, so I don't have to modify the html code to load the script.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://whatever.com/js/my/script.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: hm ok, doing it the hard way.

Answer (score 20):

A very handy command is include();

```
include("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js");
```

Read more about [include() command](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-tip-include-command/)

Comment: I tried that in the Firefox inspector on twitter's homepage and got: `ReferenceError: include is not defined.`

Comment: @isomorphismes Because that is a special command for the Firebug Console.
See the link provided by Ahmad and this for the other ones:
https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API

Answer (score 17):

Just ran into the same problem, and - as jQuery is used in the project anyway - I decided to do a simple:

```
$.getScript('example.js')
```

Or:

```
$.getScript('example.js', function () { doSomethingOnceLoaded(); })
```

Alternatively, I may code JavaScript directly in Firebug, using the console with the text entry pane on the right side. Activate it with the triangle button in the lower right hand corner.

Comment: As a jQuery user, I loved this solution.  I didn't know about getScript().  Very nice.  I also use the jQuerify plugin for Firebug.  With that, I can quickly load jQuery on a page that doesn't have it, then use your solution to load additional libraries.  Thanks!