# Big Decimal on web client

Tags: javascript, bigdecimal

I am using bigDecimal.js:

```
https://github.com/iriscouch/bigdecimal.js
```

in my node.js project server side with no problems however when I try the same on the client I can't seem to reference the bigDecimal object correctly.  On the github page it has a link:

```
http://jhs.iriscouch.com/demo/_design/bigdecimal/_show/ui?e=321.4567890*123456789.123456789987654321
```

I have a link to bigdecimal.js in my html:

```
<script src="/javascripts/bigdecimal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the script is definitely there as I can navigate to it in chrome.

my code looks like this:

```
var bd = {"BigDecimal":BigDecimal, "BigInteger":BigInteger, "RoundingMode":RoundingMode};
var bigDeletedVideoID = bd.BigInteger('9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999');
var bigLowNum = bd.BigInteger('1');
alert(bigDeletedVideoID.subtract(bigLowNum));
```

But I am getting an error in chrome on the first line saying:

```
BigDecimal is not defined.
```

Has anybody had any experience with using BigDecimal and how to do this on a javascript web client?

UPDATED:

I tested the code on localhost i.e. referencing the .js library like so:

```
http://localhost:11709/javascripts/bigdecimal.js
```

and I get the alert message appearing correctly.

But when I upload the site to the live server and now it turns into:

```
    http://pazooza.azurewebsites.net/javascripts/bigdecimal.js
```

All of a sudden I get 2 errors in particular:

- unexpected identifier bigdecimal.js line 293
- BigDecimal is not defined

Why come it works on localhost and not on the live site???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: [Load javascript via Firebug console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011817/load-javascript-via-firebug-console)

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://pazooza.azurewebsites.net/javascripts/bigdecimal.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

There doesn't seem to be any namespace conflict as I suspected before rewriting this answer:
Instead one has to be very precise of not using the symbol 'BigDecimal' *before* the js page has been loaded...

This is typically handled by onload events.

*Original suggestion was using node.js framework* or assuming namespace *BD*
as suggested by https://github.com/iriscouch/bigdecimal.js

```
 var foo=require("bigdecimal.js"); var i = foo.BigDecimal("1235");
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion Aki and I still get the error as stated in my initial post.  I tried var bigDeletedVideoID = new BD.BigInteger('...'); but no go ...