# Include a script "persistently" in Firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, include, firebug

I'm familiar with the [`include()` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15948900/80857) for loading JavaScript via Firebug. The problem I have with it is that the scripts I include using this feature do not remain between page loads. As soon as I reload it appears I have to include the script again.

For reasons I won't go into, I do not have the ability to simply add the scripts directly to the page I'm debugging. Is there a place where js files hosted locally or online can be specified to be pulled in to whatever page I load in my browser?

Comment: you describe greasemonkey, or html script tags. you can also use a bookmarklet injector to make loading a one-click thing, nearly automatic.

Comment: Thanks, @dandavis how is this done?

Comment: which one? greasemonkey you install. bookmarklets you write yourself and use the firebug console's [copy] button to turn your  loader snippet into a url-safe bookmarklet string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for that, free web debugging proxy. Just read [Injecting JavaScript into head element of website using Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933934/injecting-javascript-into-head-element-of-website-using-fiddler)

Comment: This is super nice to know about. Unfortunately, I'm connecting to the site via VPN :-(

Comment: @Keyslinger Fiddler 2.2.0.3 and later have option that allows automatic monitoring of dialup or VPN connections [link](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/MonitorDialupAndVPN)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in Firebug at the moment (version 2.0.7). Though there is a request to add this feature together with a `snippet` command in [issue 6201](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6201).

For now you can use the [aliasing functionality](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Include#alias), so you at least don't have to add the URL again and again. The initial call then looks like this:

```
include("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js", "jquery")
```

For all subsequent calls you just have to type this:

```
include("jquery")
```

These aliases are saved persistently, so they also work after a browser restart.

This doesn't make the call automatic, though it at least saves some time when including a script manually.