# Website not working properly because of jquery not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This [website](https://csgolounge.com/search) is not mine . I only use it as a guest.

Recently its stoped working properly and owners doesn't seem to take care of it. Is there a way to fix it using console or plugin ?

Looks like there is an error with loading jquery.

[image]

Comment: live is long gone in v3 change all live function to on

Comment: No. There is no way for you to 'fix' the site without access to their code and servers that the code is deployed on. You *might* be able to change some of the JS in the console but this will be cleared every time you reload the page. Unfortunately I don't think that this question can be answered in the scope of [so].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to inject an obsolete version of Jquery in your browser, try (in your console):

```
(function(){
$.noConflict(); // turns off the namespace $ for newer jq 
var script = document.createElement('script')
script.src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"
document.body.appendChild(script)
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

`.live` has been deprecated and removed in current versions of jQuery. You need to use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

If you don't have access to the website FTP then there is no way you can change the jquery `.live` to `.on`. Even if you have access to FTP then you need to search in the source code for `.live` and replace it everywhere with `.on`.

Comment: Is there a way to externaly load older  version of jquery that uses .live() ?

Comment: @MHB, I think it wont work, but still you can try including your script using : 

`var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://whatever.com/js/my/script.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);`

Source : 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3011839/1206449

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .live() has been removed in version 1.9 onwards.

so use .on instead of live function

Comment: Can i do it if i am not the owner of the site and how ? I cant find .live() anywhere.